# UITableViewCell Custom Indentation Width

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uidevice

My app includes a `UITableViewController`. The default indentation (while editing) is fine, except when on an iPad in landscape mode, when the indentation is way too wide. I've tried setting the `indentationWidth` and `indentationLevel` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but nothing seems to work.

I would like my code to work something like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
  cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",
                                                           forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // do other cell configuration here
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        // set the custom indentation level for the cell here
        // Tried:
        // cell.indentationWidth = 0.1
        // cell.indentationLevel = 0
        // both have absolutely no effect
    }
}
```

***The horrible indentation on iPad in landscape:***
[image: editing]
***The same cells while not editing:***
[image: not editing]
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Some pictures would be very helpful to understand.

Comment: @liushuaikobe Thanks for the advice. I added some screenshots for clarity.

Comment: Show the code where you set the indentation level.

Answer (score 2):

In viewDidLoad, add the following line:

```
self.tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth=NO;
```

The default setting is YES and that causes wide margins in landscape on newer iPads.